# map_view flutter, how to change plugin to add variable location latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, plugins, flutter

hello I don't know how to change map_view plugin : localition.dart,  to be abble to use variable latitude and longitude . Not a fix lat and long as currently.

https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/tree/master/lib

locations.dart ( plugin map_view ):

```
import 'location.dart';

class Locations {
  static Location portland = new Location(37.0902, 37.0902);
  static Location centerOfUSA = new Location(37.0902, -95.7192);
}
```

main.dart ( app ):

```
@override
initState() {
super.initState();


cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(Locations.portland, 2.0);
staticMapUri = staticMapProvider.getStaticUri(Locations.portland, 20,
    width: 900, height: 400, mapType: StaticMapViewType.hybrid );
}
```

I want to change change portland with my double lat and double long.

Answer (score 0):

`Locations.portland` is just an example probably used in testing or something. You can use any location you want with `new Location(<your latitude>, <your longitude>);` i.e. `new Location(48.8583,2.2944);`.

So that would be

```
staticMapUri = staticMapProvider.getStaticUri(
  new Location(48.8583,2.2944), 20,
  width: 900, height: 400, mapType: StaticMapViewType.hybrid,
);
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, I tried, but I have a message  " NoShuchMethodeError: The getter 'center' was called on null, Receiver : null, Tried calling : center .   I think I need to communicate with le plugin  (static_map_provider) but I can't link her double latitude, longitude with my double lat long. I tried to import my page into the plugin but my double was not recongnized.